# Who is this brown-haired witch on a broomstick?

Tags: merchandise

I wasn't able to contact the owner of this product, but would anyone be able to tell me who the character is/what they're from? It would be much appreciated! Thank you!!

[image: anime? character]

Answer (score 7):

Sakamaki Laito from "Diabolik Lovers": he is wearing the same suit and the the same look on his face also same hair color and eye color. I couldn't find this keychain anywhere but if you look up his name there is the same image on tumblr (he is a boy and a vampire by the way) this must be a Halloween costume. Anyway here is his image on zerochan :)

[image]

Comment: To confirm your answer: the same keychain is sold in [this website](http://www.suruga-ya.jp/product/detail/608304627001), where the name of the character (逆巻ライト) appear.

Answer (score 5):

This could be Alice, from [Mahō Shōjotai Arusu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweeny_Witches) (or Magical Girl Squad, or Tweeny Witches). However, there are some obvious differences between the image in the question and Alice in the anime. I'm not sure if these stem from a stylistic choice on the part of the artist who made the product, or if I am wrong about who this is meant to be. *As of Mimo's answer, I can confirm I was definitely wrong.*

[image]